# eval JS in AJAX loaded contents

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'd like to load this code (1) via XMLHttpRequest in another page

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="info(event)"/>
<script>
  function info(e) { console.log(e.keyCode); }
</script>
```

This (2) is the way I tried...

```
<div id="x"></div>
<script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = handleResponse.bind(xhr);
  xhr.open("POST","test.php",true);
  xhr.send();

  function handleResponse() {
    var x = document.getElementById("x");
    x.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    var js = x.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    eval(js.innerText);
  }
</script>
```

...and this is the error I got on keypress:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: info is not defined
```

Why the `info()` is not found since its definition was eval'd? How to make the info fire on keypress if (2) should be unaware of (1)? No jQuery.

Following Mike's recommendation, I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17252150/343721) to solve separated problem that leads to explanation of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

(edited for es202020, because JS has changed *drastically* since 2013 and the old answer is now an anti-pattern. Don't use `eval`)

---

Scope. You didn't eval it on `window`, you added it to the scope of that function `handleResponse` so it won't exist outside of handleResponse. Also, in this case you don't really need `eval` at all, just create a script element and add that:

```
function handleResponse(evt) {
  const s = document.createElement(`script`);
  s.textContent = evt.responseText;
  document.head.appendChild(s);

}
```

The browser already knows how to interpret scripts, but you need to add elements to the `head` if you want them to execute instead of be inserted as inactive DOM nodes after the page has already loaded.

Don't use `eval()`.

Comment: `NodeList` doesn't have a `slice` method. You mean `[].slice.call(NodeList)`? I also know that eval is evil, but inserted script is not executed without it (if it contains say `alert(1)`). Inserting script into head doesn't seem to work. Have you tested it? `new Function` hides scope, so it doesn't replace eval (i.e.: `var x=42;`).

Comment: oops, sorry, let me edit that, because that should indeed just be slice.call -- eval isn't evil, evalling code of which you don't know what it is is just bad programming, and given how you can inject code in a browser, it's just almost never required. Eval's a high precision gun that you need to use *really* carefully. As for inserting script into head: proven technology, it's how you run dynamic scripts. Example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xh4pQ/

Comment: I was playing with your notices and made it work! But there's still something left to answer, see my updated question.

Comment: that's actually a different question - usually it's a good idea to ask that as a separate issue so people can search for it and find it when they run into the same problem in the future. I'm not sure why that's happening, but would recommend asking it as a different SO post after isolating it to a test case that reproduces that.